# Copying permissions for groups django

Tags: python, django

I want to copy group permissions from one place to another. 
This is my code:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User, Group

user_ids = Permission.objects.filter(codename='bags').values_list('user', flat=True)
groups = Permission.objects.filter(codename='bags').values_list('group', flat=True)
new = Permission.objects.get(codename='bags_new')

for user in User.objects.filter(~Q(user_permissions__in=[new]), id__in=user_ids):
    user.user_permissions.add(new)
```

Till here it is working fine. My problem is when i try to copy for groups its not working. I have tried the following:

```
for group1 in Group.objects.filter(~Q(groups_permissions__in=[new]), id__in=groups):
    group1.group.permissions.add(new)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show what error you getting? i think  ***group1.group.permissions.add(new)*** this is wrong

Comment: Am not getting an error. Its not working correctly

Comment: group1.permissions.add(new)  ***just try this instad*** group1.group.permissions.add(new)

Comment: Any way i can copy the group permissions? This code is not working right even with that change

Comment: i would not call it a copy ! you can add the same permission to another group.

Comment: How should i add those same permissions to the other groups?

Comment: *Permission_list = Permission.objects.all()
newgroup.permissions.add(Permission_list)* try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156017/discussion-between-taniya-and-manan-kalariya).